# Can I adjust the memory cache size differently for different databases?

Tags: caching, sqlite

I have an application that uses SQLite. It uses seven different database files, each with a connection created with `sqlite3_open`. Six of these aren't performance critical, but one is.

I'd like to increase the memory caching on the performance-critical database connection using `PRAGMA cache_size`. However, this changes the cache size for all connections. I don't have enough memory for each of the seven databases to use as much memory as I need the performance-critical one to use.

I've confirmed that the setting does affect all connections. And I've confirmed that there's no common pool -- each connection is individually limited to the specified memory amount.

Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PRAGMA cache_size` affects only one database connection.

Ensure that your connections are not [shared](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) (with `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache` or `SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE`).

Comment: I just tested again more carefully and you are right. The setting does not affect all connections.